# Accessibility return to first element ios swift

Tags: ios, swift

Is there a way to bring focus back to the first element in a screen for Accessibility. For example: If you go through and entire screen using accessibility voice over and you come to the bottom of the screen now if you want to go back up the next swipe should take us back to the first element on top

Comment: I believe this sort of jump would be against accessibility: imagine you got to last element on the screen, next swipe right doesn't do anything. OK, so you know you got to last element, and can swipe left to go to previous elements. Now imagine you go back to first element after swiping right on last element. At that point user is confused: they may not remember what the first element was, so they assume it's a continuation of the same screen. They keep swiping, completely disoriented on where exactly on the screen they are. Better to have first and last elements clearly stopping

Comment: Besides, there's a special gesture that allows you to go to the first element on the screen at any time (Select the first item on the screen = Four-finger tap near the top of the screen), see: https://support.apple.com/en-ca/guide/iphone/iph3e2e2281/ios